# Hibernate Criteria do not add schema to table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have three tables device , vehicle and vehicle_device all tables are in one schema 'tcm' and I'm trying to get 'vehicle' by 'device imei' . In Vehicle.class i have field 'Set devices' and create maping:

Vehicle.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping package="hibernate.entity">
<class name="Vehicle" table="vehicles" schema="tcm">
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
       <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">tcm.vehicles_id_seq</param>
        </generator>
    </id>       
    .
    .
    .
    <set name="devices" table="vehicle_device"
        inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all" >
        <key>
            <column name="vehicle_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="hibernate.entity.Device">
            <column name="device_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>

</class>
```

when execute  criteria to take the results for needed 'device imei'

```
@Override
public Vehicle getVehicleByDeviceImei(String imei) {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Vehicle.class);
    criteria.createAlias("devices", "devices").add(Restrictions.eq("devices.imei", imei));
    Vehicle v = (Vehicle) criteria.uniqueResult();
    return v;
}
```

Everything is OK except that the query that is generated does not add schema 'tcm' for the link table 'vehicle_device' in first inner join

```
select       .
             .
             .
             .
from
    tcm.vehicles this_ 
inner join
    vehicle_device devices3_ 
        on this_.id=devices3_.vehicle_id 
inner join
    devices devices1_ 
        on devices3_.device_id=devices1_.id 
where
    devices1_.device_imei=?
```

and have an error :
 ERROR:  relation "vehicle_device" does not exist
LINE 17:         vehicle_device devices3_

If i add manual schema  to generated query --> 'tcm.vehicle_device' it work.
how to fix my configuration so Hibernate Criteria adds the schema for table 'vehicle_device'.

Comment: can you share your `hibernate-configuration` cfg file ?

Answer (score 0):

I fix problem. I just added scheme = 'tcm'  in set tag in mapping